# Implementing Finite State Machine for Web UI

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am intending to develop a Finite State Machine in the following manner.

1. Extract Control IDs from a --> web-page,
2. Write control IDs to a XML -->  Controls-XML.
3. Manually declare States and Transition in the --> Controls-XML
4. Scan Controls-XML and attach pre-declared Jscript to eventhandlers embed them in the --> web-page..
   5.

How feasible this would be..

Am I getting into can of worms ?

Comment: I am leaning on TT (Text transformation tool) to do this..

Comment: Are you reinventing XUL?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL

Comment: Be a hell of a lot easier to use JSON instgead of XML if you're working primarially in js.

Answer (score 1):

First, we live in a can of worms!

your questions are a bit vague, please provide more details if i'm missing your point and maybe this should be beak in parfts to deepen the discution in part details

assuming you want to work live on a client side browser over any page

by extrating ID's of controls i supouse it's all controls of a webpage (it could be by clicking or clicking possibly with key combos), but lets be simple.

**Extrating ID's**

here's a code than might help you:

```
function scan(e) {
  if (e&&e.childNodes)
  for(var i=0;i<e.childNodes.length;i++) {
    var child=e.childNodes[i];
    if (child) {
      if(child.id) console.log(child.nodeName,child.id);
      scan(child);
    }
  }
}
```

note: this was done with chrome, but any browser console will do i think.

just paste the function on the console and then call it like:

```
scan(document)
```

and it will list (on console) all elements that have id's showing element type and id... you can filter that eazy by just printing elements of certain tags like INPUT, SELECT TEXTAREA, etc...

**About the XML**

here browsers get a bit tricky, you can simplify it too your favorite browser, the following functions constructs a XML document given some XML text.
So by this aproach your scan function should compose the xml text (instead of writing to the console) and later we can feed the XML document

```
function makeNode(text) {
var doc;
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    doc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    doc.async="false";
    doc.loadXML(text);
} else {// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    var parser=new DOMParser();
    doc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
}// documentElement always represents the root node
return doc.documentElement;
}
```

other aproach is to create an empty XML document (as the above function does) and the instead of feed raw xml text your scan function should use XMLDOM commands to insert nodes into the document.

**Manually declare States and Transition in the --> Controls-XML**

this is an hard one, is this (XML doc) info to be copy/pasted and latter edited? is it edited inplace by inserting a bunch of code to build an interface?

many doubts here, but once we have the information in XML format we would be free to use our imagination and decide a format to handle the wanted state changes.

**Scan Controls-XML and attach pre-declared Jscript to eventhandlers embed them in the --> web-page**

at this point actions depend on methods followed above, but in any case using XMLDOM functions to traverse the xml doc and apply status change or event handlers to the controls is trivial.

controls need not be scanned anymore because we have stored the id's (use getElementById)

i have a form validation system that does something similar, except the XML is predefined and stored on server side, but once loaded it will do just that. attaching event handlers and do status changes based on evaluated expressions.